# Can I use docker to run MSBuild on OSX?

Tags: .net, macos, iis, docker, msbuild

At work we have a large JS(FrontEnd)/.NET(BackEnd) project. I want to have an option to work on the project on a Mac at home. Can I use docker for working both on PC and on Mac for the same project? I have been told, that the current system doesn't work well with the classic .NET, only optimized for .NET core. Is that correct?

Comment: No.  Run Windows in a virtual machine (vmware or virtualbox or parallels) and install your usual development environment in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build it if you're willing to use only .NET Core, per [these directions](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/wiki/Building-Testing-and-Debugging-on-.Net-Core-MSBuild). However you are correct that you need Windows to get the full .NET Framework. And at this point you can only use Windows Docker containers on Windows 10 pro or Windows Server 2016, not Mac or Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Mono 4.8+ includes a distribution of `msbuild` that can build csproj projects. Mono 5 is going to include the SDKs required to build the "new-style" csproj format for .net core / .net standard (4.8 can be [patched manually](https://gist.github.com/dasMulli/29c7d68f321cc5ac4a68407a6fd76d19)).

The [omnisharp project](http://www.omnisharp.net) also brings C# editing capabilities to a lot of editors and works on macOS. So does the C# extension for [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com) (which is found on [GitHub](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode) and powers by [omnisharp-roslyn](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/issues)). Microsoft also offers Visual Studio for Mac so you can have a similar editing experience for your projects across macOS and Windows.
There also is the JetBrains Rider projects which aims to create a non-microsoft cross-platform IDE.

Comment: Sounds like an overkill for only a 'build'. Hope, the future will be more platform - (read Microsoft) - agnostic